# Using JAVA on heroku Flask App

Tags: java, python, heroku

I have created and deployed a Flask app on heroku, but some of the code for my app, requires Java. When I run the code it says that JAVAHOME is not set. I tried

```
heroku run 'which java'
```

But nothing happens, and I cannot find java executable, nor the directory to set JAVAHOME manually. My question is, is it possible to have a Flask app which uses code that needs java (a java.jar)?

Comment: you may just need to request a java instance and link it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the JVM buildpack to your app by running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy.